# Syntax error when trying to make a comparison

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

```
return render_template('books.html', username=session['username'], mybooks=q)
```

```
<html>
  Welcome {{username}}

  {% for book in mybooks %}
    {% if book.author == {{username}}%}
         <p>Author: {{ book.author }}</p>
         <p>Edition: {{book.edition}}</p>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</html>
```

I dont't understand why I get an error when I try to compare:

```
{% if book.author == {{username}}%}
```

The error message:

```
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ':', got '}'
```

Comment: Why are you encasing `username` in braces? You aren't allowed to do in "logic" code and just `if book.author == username` should be what you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{{..}}` is not needed, you are not putting a value in the output. Just compare *directly* with the variable:

```
{% if book.author == username %}
```